# KML - Multiple Styles In One PlaceMark

Tags: xml, kml

What I have is a placemark that contains more than one linestring. Is it possible to assign different styles to those linestrings inside the one placemark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing. Just include a `<styleUrl>#MyOtherStyleID</styleUrl>` (if you're keeping them that way) before every one of your `<LineString>...</LineString>` sections.